# How to destroy current screen and navigate to another screen ? so that on back press that previous screen doesn't appear

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Hello everyone i am new to react-native and stuck in a navigation problem. i have crawled through every question about this but found nothing helpful.

I have Navigation structure like this

Tab Navigator

1. HomeStack [mainScreen,Screen2]
2. PostStack[cameraScreen,UploadPostScreen]

Now i want to navigate to MainScreen of HomeStack after uploading the Post and along with that i want to remove these post and upload screen so that i can not go back by pressing back button.

Comment: Does https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#reset (`navigation.reset`) help you?

Comment: instead of using this.props.navigation.navigate('Your Component Name') use this.props.navigation.replace('Your Component Name') replace You will achieve it.

Comment: I tried  using navigation.reset but it did not work , even tried dispatching reset action but it does nothing and doesn't even give any error. replace is also not working in my case

Comment: try navigation.replace('screen name')

Comment: i did try  navigation.replace('screen name') but it is not working but when i try  navigation.navigate('screen name') it works fine. I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Not working - what do you mean? It throws an error, it fails, what does it do?

Comment: I tried replace with renaming my screens and now it works perfect thanks to all above for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `replace` method in that case, take a look here:

`https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace`

Answer (score 1):

in my case,

I have just used

```
props.navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'Login'
    }
  ]
});
```